# React Native: 'componentWillReceiveProps' clearing Dropdown Selected Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a form which consists of two drop down list fields (amongst other form elements), using [React Native Modal Dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-dropdown) plugin. The two dropdowns are:

1. Country List
2. States list (filtered by the what country that was selected above)

I am currently having a problem with the States Dropdown, which recieves a `countryId` value from state that is set when a item is selected from the the Country Drop Down. This is then used to pass to my State Drop Down.

It's worth noting that the two dropdown's I have listed above have been seperated into components for reusability.

Code for Form:

```
static propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.object
};

state = {
    countryId: 0,
    stateId: 0
}

componentWillMount() {
}

onCountryDropDownSelected = (val) => {
    this.setState({ countryId: val });
}

onStateDropDownSelected = (val) => {
    this.setState({ stateId: val });
}

render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
            <CountryDropDownList onSelect={this.onCountryDropDownSelected} />
            <Text>Country: {this.state.countryId}</Text>
            <StateDropDownList onSelect={this.onStateDropDownSelected} countryId={this.state.countryId} />
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Code for StateDropDownList component:

```
class StateDropDownList extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        countryId: PropTypes.number,
        onSelect: PropTypes.func
    };

    state = {
        data: [],
        errorMessage: '',
        isLoading: false
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.countryId != undefined) {
            return this.populatePicker(nextProps.countryId);
        }
    }

    populatePicker(countryId) {
        // This method fetches data from the API to store in the 'data' state object.
    }

    dropDownRenderRow(rowData, rowID, highlighted) {
        let evenRow = rowID % 2;

        return (
            <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='cornflowerblue'>
                <View style={{backgroundColor: evenRow ? 'lemonchiffon' : 'white'}}>
                    <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>
                        {rowData.name}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }

    dropDownRenderButtonText(rowData) {
        console.log('dropDownRenderButtonText', rowData);
        return rowData.name;
    }

    dropDownRenderSeparator(sectionID, rowID, adjacentRowHighlighted) {
        return (<View key={rowID} />);
    }

    dropDownOnSelect(rowID, rowData) {
        // Get the selected value and pass to parent component through onSelect() event in parent.
        this.props.onSelect(rowData.id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Home State</Text>
                {this.state.data && this.state.data.length > 0 ?
                    <ModalDropdown defaultValue='Select one'
                          style={{flex:1}, {marginTop: 10}}
                          options={this.state.data}
                           onSelect={(rowID, rowData) => this.dropDownOnSelect(rowID, rowData)}
                          renderButtonText={(rowData) => this.dropDownRenderButtonText(rowData)}
                          renderRow={this.dropDownRenderRow.bind(this)}
                          renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID, adjacentRowHighlighted) => this.dropDownRenderSeparator(sectionID, rowID, adjacentRowHighlighted)} />
                    :
                        <Text>No regions for country.</Text>
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

What I am noticing is that the 'componentWillReceiveProps' function is stopping my dropdown from having a selected value. But unfortunately, I need this function in order for the props to update when passing in the `countryId` value from the parent.

When I remove the `this.props.onSelect(rowData.id);` line in this dropDownOnSelect() function, the dropdown value gets set correctly. I guess this is the case, since I am not setting an prop value.

I can see what the issue is, but not a way to get around it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. Made a simple error to check if the `nextProps.countryId` is not the same as `props.countryId`, which now makes sense:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.countryId && nextProps.countryId != this.props.countryId) {
        return this.populatePicker(nextProps.countryId);
    }
}
```